# Acid testing a http server

Tags: c, http, robustness

Is there any apps that can test a http server for robustness.

It would be great if it can send corrupt headers, missing headers,
thrashing, attempting to keep connections open etc..

I'm writing a embedded http server in C..

Comment: [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

[I'd throw the Apache test at it](http://httpd.apache.org/test/).